Unable to login: Email/password login form broken due to duplicated hidden fields
On Chrome (123.0.6312.87, macOS 13.6.6) I am unable to log in via email and password on https://stackoverflow.com/users/login because the visible inputs are duplicated by visually hidden inputs sharing the same names.
Steps to repro:

Enter a value in email and password.
Click "Log in".
verify that you see the validation errors "Email cannot be empty." and "Password cannot be empty."

Workaround: Delete the hidden elements via devtools before submitting the form.
Screenshots:



the form
console warnings










According to the main space post that prompted a duplicate Meta question, this is also reproduced on Firefox and therefore not browser-specific.

It appears that the signup form is hidden on the login page and so resulting in duplicate IDs that are checked by the validation. Therefore it will impact all users.

This issue has been resolved and lasted for approximately 6 hours. Just some older html that was clashing with new authentication stuff.

I wonder how many hours this issue will take to resolve? Thanks.
